# Serve static html files in PWA if service worker is configured in CRA

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I want to serve static html files e.g. privacy.html, terms.html in PWA (built with Create-React-App ) with service worker configured. On Localhost I can access the files like

> ```
> http://locahost://terms.html
> http://localhost://privacy.html
> ```

but when serve the build (**server -s build**) or deploy to host, I get a blank page. I tried to implement multiple solutions to access static files but unable to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the app in CRA, It would create a `build` directory for you and put the file that it builds in it, in order to have `privacy.html` in the build directory, you could manually put the copy of `privacy.html` in the build directory, or use a command like this:

```
    cp current/path/to/privacy.html build/privacy.html
```

a better way is to build its script and add it to your `package.json` file and call it at the end of the current build script, in this way, each time that you build your app, it automatically does that for you:

package.json

```
"build-static-html-page": "cp current/path/to/privacy.html build/privacy.html",
"build": "CURRENT_BUILD_SCRIPT",
"build-project": "build build-static-html-page"
```